# \textbf{text} without increasing the length of the text

Tags: beamer, fonts, macros, bold

When using `\textbf{text}`, the length of `text` will be increased. Is there a way to make the `text` bold face without increasing its length?

edit:

Thanks to @Herbert and @Martin, here is a perfect solution for me:

```
   \newsavebox\CBox 
   \newcommand<>*\textBF[1]{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\textbf#2{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\CBox
\def\textBF#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\textbf{#1}}}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
foobarbaz y\\
\textbf{foobarbaz} y\\
\textBF{foobarbaz} y

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example for `beamer`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newsavebox\CBox
\newcommand<>*\textBF[1]{\only#2{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
\only<1>{foobarbaz y1} 
\textbf<2->{foobarbaz y2}
\textBF<3>{foobarbaz y3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another (better) possibility is to use the letter spacing option from the package `microtype`

Comment: is it possible to make it work with `beamer` overlays? --e.g.`\textBF<1>{text}`

Comment: use it this way: `\only<1>{\textBF{text}}` or put this definition into `\def\textBF`itself.

Comment: It should be `\newcommand<>\textBF[1]{\only#2{\sbox\CBox...}}`, where the dots mean all the rest in Herbert's definition.

Comment: @Herbert: Humm, using `\only` here will lead to a different effect in my situation --- i.e. the `text` will disappear in other slides.

Comment: @Lee: then you do not have a `\only<1->` so that it appears from slide 1 up to the end. Right?

Comment: @Herbert: humm, I do not fully understand the usage of `\only`. How could I make `\only<3>{\textbf{text}}` works like `\textbf<3>{text}`?

Comment: @egreg: sorry for missing your reply. Could you please write a full solution? I couldn't make it to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lee: `\newsavebox\CBox
\newcommand<>*\textBF[1]{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\textbf#2{#1}}}` works for me. There was some funny invisible unicode character in the code of my last comment. It might have caused that (Herbert: Feel free to add this code to your answer)

Comment: Martin and Herbert: thank you soooooooooooooooooo much! A perfect solution for me:)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\fontseries{b}\selectfont` to select a non-extended bold font, provided of course that the font family you're using contains such a font (as computer modern does). For comparison, note that `\textbf` uses `\fontseries{bx}`, where the `x`stands for “extended”.

Comment: In my opinion, the visual difference between Computer Modern's medium and non-extended-bold fonts isn't all that big. As a result, viewers of a beamer presentation might not even notice the intended effect of alternating between those two fonts.

Comment: @Mico: You have a point there. I was in a hurry and hadn't noticed that this was for a beamer presentation (which wasn't clear from the question itself). But I'll let the answer stand for future reference, since this is an option that should at least be considered.

Comment: I agree, it's good to mention the option of using a non-extended bold form of the Computer Modern roman (serif) fonts.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just for adding overlay support to Herber's command, who should credited for it.

```
\newcommand<>\textBF[1]{\only#2{\dotextBF}{#1}}
\newcommand\dotextBF[1]{\sbox0{#1}\resizebox{\wd0}{\ht0}{\textbf{#1}}}

...

\textBF<2->{xyz}
```

"xyz" will be bold from the second screen onwards.

I don't think it's a good way to emphasize things on screen; colors are better.

Comment: I am actually using both bold and color.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following macro instead. It uses the size of the horizontal and vertical size of the normal text, but sets it as bold text which makes the bold text lap over the text which follows. The text is also not breakable any longer. For overlays of table cells this should be fine but I wouldn't use it in running text of course.

```
\newcommand*{\textBF}[1]{\rlap{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}\phantom{#1}}
```

If you want to support `beamer` overlays use:

```
\newcommand<>*{\textBF}[1]{\only#2{\rlap{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}\phantom}{#1}}
```

or

```
\newcommand<>*{\textBF}[1]{\alt#2{\rlap{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}\phantom{#1}}{\mbox{#1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you know I am using it for overlays of table cells?...It seems that I couldn't use it in this way: `\textBF<1>{text}`?

Comment: I tried to `\newcommand*{\textBF}[2]{\rlap{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf<#1>{#2}}}\phantom{#2}}` But it seems that it does not work.

Comment: @Lee: see my update.

Comment: hummm, I am not sure whether it is working in my table. It seems that if the `text` of the `\textBF{text}` is at the end, the length of the cell is still affected. BTW, it seems that I couldn't mention your name...

Comment: @Lee: Try the second version now.

Comment: I Tried both methods, but still does not work for text at the end in a cell....

Comment: @Lee: I would need to see an example. Feel free to edit your question to add it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/886/discussion-between-user2015-and-martin-scharrer)

Comment: Martin: the problem is on my side, your solution works too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to (or allowed to) switch to typewriter (monospaced) font, you won't encounter the problem: the regular and bold fonts have glyphs of the exact same widths.

The following MWE uses `Courier` (scaled 5% in order to equate the cap-heights of the mono and text fonts in use), because in that font the difference between medium weight and bold is particularly strong. The `lmodern` package has a bold mono font as well, but the difference to the medium weight isn't as pronounced.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[scaled=1.05]{couriers} %%
\begin{document}
\noindent
\texttt{The quick brown fox 012456789}\\
\texttt{\bfseries The quick brown fox 012456789}
\end{document}
```

Another font package possibility you may want to consider is `arev`. (Given that you seem to be preparing for a beamer presentation, using the `arev` package would be a good choice anyway.) In the arev package, the mono font harmonizes well with the text font (which is a sans-serif font), and the medium and bold mono fonts are quite different.

Comment: Yes, I can change the font. Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: @Lee: I've added an example to my answer above.

Comment: is it possible to use this technique on my current font?

Comment: Lee: What font family are you currently using?