# Beamer \color overlay with more than one color

Tags: beamer, color, overlays

By using `\color<3-4>{blue}{text}`, the `text` will be blue on slides 3 and 4, and black on other slides. Is it possible to make the `text` red on slide 1 at the same time?

Comment: Note that your example should be either `\textcolor<3-4>{blue}{text}` or `{\color<3-4>{blue}text}`.

Answer (score 19):

```
\textcolor<1>{red}{\color<3-4>{blue}text}
```

Inner specifications will override outer ones.

Comment: I am actually try to use two different colors for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23678/2015. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following layout on your slide:

```
\textcolor<1>{red}{text1}  
\<2> {text2}  % item 2 in standard (black) color
\textcolor<3>{blue}{text3}
\textcolor{4>{blue}{text4}
<5> etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works fine...

```
\color<1>{red} \color<3-4>{blue} text
```