# Bold row in table aligned with dcolumn

Tags: tables, dcolumn

I am generating a bunch of TeX-tables (with Stata), in which one particular row has to be highlighted (bold). I can however only modify the first column in there, hence I want to place a command in the first cell of column to make it bold(or not)

So far I've been using this "[Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold)", which does exactly what I want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{dcolumn}    
\newcolumntype{X}{>{\rowstyle{\relax}}l}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\currentrowstyle}c}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{XYY}
normal row & 1.1 & 2.2\\
bold row \rowstyle{\bfseries} & 1.1 & 2.2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now, I decided to switch to `dcolumn`, which is great, but breaks the bold-workaround, as it wraps cells in mathmode. The solution David provided here ([Decimals in table don't align with dcolumn when bolded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118458/decimals-in-table-dont-align-with-dcolumn-when-bolded)) does not really work either, as it would require a `\multicolumn{1}{B}{...}` in every bold cell.

Simply using `mathbf` instead doesnt seem to do the trick. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "outside of LaTeX"? Please show us some code of yours to play around with. Just one of the tables in a compilable environment.

Comment: You should take a look at the `numprint` package (§6 of the documentation: `Printing aligned numbers in tabulars`). It can manage bold numbers (in text and math modes) and non-numeric extra content of cells.

Comment: As David Carlisle explains in the answer you link to, `\bfseries` can't work because `dcolumn` uses math mode.

Comment: This is why I wrote "which is great, but breaks the bold-workaround, as it wraps cells in mathmode" just after the link. I am searching for away to solve this. I am sorry if that was not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{dcolumn}  

\makeatletter  
\newcolumntype{X}{>{\rowstyle{\relax}}l}
\newcolumntype{D}[3]{>{\currentrowstyle\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{XD..{-1}D..{-1}}
normal row & 1.1 & 2.2\\
bold row \rowstyle{\bfseries\boldmath} & 1.1 & 2.2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work, (at least not with the MWE above), as the `\boldmath` will end up being /within/ the math mode of the cell

Comment: @sheß I added an image to my answer: the digits look bold to me.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not sure what i messed up. you are right of course

Comment: Ah, now I see, is it actually using a D-column in your example?

Comment: @sheß :-) Oh I didn't check I just assumed the example you provided was an example. I'll fix....

Comment: @sheß try now, answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

A solution with package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{X}{%
  >{\rowstyle{\relax}}l%
}
\newcolumntype{Y}{%
  >{\currentrowstyle}S[detect-weight]%
}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{%
  \protected\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{XYY}
    normal row & 1.1 & 2.2\\
    normal row & 12.34 & 56.78\\
    bold row \rowstyle{\bfseries} & 1.1 & 2.2\\
    bold row \rowstyle{\bfseries} & 12.34 & 56.78\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: great, i use this for now. i will just not (for now) mark it as accepted answer since it is technically not an answer to the question(-title).

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
\newsavebox\CBox
\def\mathBF#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\best}[1]{\mathBF{#1}}  % for table
```

And then in the table, just `\best{1.1}` or wherever you want to have some number in bold.

This is specifically for math mode and works well together with `siunitx`.

Inspired from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23678/textbftext-without-increasing-the-length-of-the-text).
Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553854/2272).