# Fake Semibold (bold without increasing the length of the text)

Tags: bold

The font I am using doesn't have a semibold weights.

I would like to fake a bold font that has a similar width to the regular font.

I tried using this approach from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23691/41036:

```
\newsavebox\CBox
\def\textBF#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}\resizebox{\wd\CBox}{\ht\CBox}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

It works very well for single words, however doesn't allow line-breaks etc.

How can I redefine this command to use it for longer expressions, most preferably like I would usually use `\bfseries` (e.g., by defining a new command like `\bfsemiseries`)?

Kindest regards,
Mil

Comment: It is not too difficult to take a font, and create a semibold font, using FontForge. Menu Element > Style > Change Weight, maybe 10 units. If the font has a lot of glyphs but you are only using a small portion of them, then you can limit the change to only the used characters. This assumes that you have a suitable font license.

Answer (score 6):

You can't extend this command. But you can use a pdfliteral (assuming that you use pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\newcommand{\textBF}[1]{%
    \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 0.3 w} %the second factor is the boldness
     #1%
    \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
some text 

\textBF{some text}

\textbf{some text}

\lipsum[1]

\textBF{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the answer to this related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102578/fake-bold-in-lualatex/102706#102706 the thickened font may look OK on screen, but not necessarily when printed to paper. Perhaps it is a matter of expectations?

Answer (score 2):

The `fontspec` package supports the `FakeBold` font option.  You can either use `\newfontfamily\somefamily{Some Font}[FakeBold=1.2]` or `\addfontfeature{FakeBold=1.2}` (or whatever number you prefer, but normal weight is 1.0 and a typical value for bold is 1.5).

If you want to add a semibold weight that you can select with commands such as `\sbseries` and `\textsb{}`, here is an example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif}[
  Scale = 1.0,
  Ligatures = {Common, Discretionary, TeX},
  UprightFont = * ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{ Font={*}, FakeBold = 1.2 },
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{ Font={*-Italic}, FakeBold = 1.2 },
  Extension = .ttf
]

% The commands to select semibold weight:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

DejaVu \textit{Serif} \\
\textbf{Bold \textit{Italic}} \\
\textsb{\textit{Fake} Semibold} 

\end{document}
```

[image: DejaVu Serif Sample]

Comment: I found that `FakeBold=1.0`, when applied to regular weight, actually produced bolder text. However, `FakeBold=0.0` seems to be the actual “normal weight”. Unfortunately the XeTeX manual doesn’t explain how `embolden` works, but I think it is additive rather than multiplicative as you stated.

Comment: Awesome option. By the way, `AutoFakeBold` is even better since it only affects `\textbf`-embedded text. See this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569750/262813.