# How to make "fakebold" work on custom font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, texpad

I am including a special font for greek, but when I use it, the `\textbf{}` command does not result in bold letters. I have added a `[FakeBold=3]`, but it has no effect. What's the problem?

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={* Semibold},ItalicFont={* Italic},BoldItalicFont={* Semibold Italic}]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bgkfamily[FakeBold=3]{SBL Greek}
%%% \newfontfamily\bgkfamily[BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2.5}]{SBL Greek}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bgreek}{\bgkfamily\upshape}
\begin{document}
    Here is a sentence. This is \bgreek{και \textbf{και } και}
\end{document}
```

In case it matters, I am using Texpad.

Comment: First of all, how do you compile? With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Texpad has its own built in renderer, I am using that. (Texpad can't compile all types of tex documents, but when it can't, it pushes your document to the 'cloud' and compiles it)

Comment: Iirc (and I just checked with https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/typesetting) you can choose. In your case you should check that it is XeLaTeX (LuaLaTeX does not support fake boldening).

Comment: Why use Times New Roman Semi Bold when you want something bolder?

Comment: Hi @RuixiZhang, I am trying to work out how to select an alternate font that bold doesn't work, and make it so that alternate font can become bold.    (Times already has bold, I don't have questions about trying to make Times bold.)

Comment: Do you want `FakeBold=` as a top-level option, which bolds the regular text too, or `AutoFakeBold=`? If you’re asking why `\textbf` doesn’t make the text any bolder, that’s your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not completely sure I understand what you’re asking.  However, if you give `FakeBold` as a top-level font option, you’ll make all faces of the font heavier.  If you don’t have another bold font, your bold text won’t get any bolder.

To automatically embolden only the bold faces and slant only the slanted and italic faces, use `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}

% Intentionally loading these fonts in a way that prevents finding NewCM10-Bold.otf.
\newfontfamily\fakebolded{NewCM10-Regular.otf}[FakeBold=1.5, FakeSlant=0.25]
\newfontfamily\autobolded{NewCM10-Regular.otf}[AutoFakeBold=1.5, AutoFakeSlant=0.25]

\begin{document}
Real \textbf{Bold \textsl{Slanted}}

\fakebolded Fake \textbf{Bold \textsl{Slanted}}

\autobolded Auto-Fake \textbf{Bold \textit{Slanted}}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

Comment: Where can I find the documentation of `newcomputermodern` to understand the meaning of option `regular`? and how to disable its ligatures?

Comment: @Diaa (Nearly) all LaTeX packages are on [CTAN.](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern) Look there first.

Comment: @Diaa You might also have downloaded the PDF documentation for every package as part of a full TeX Live install, although most other distributions save you the disk space.

Comment: @Diaa The command to load New Computer Modern with no common ligatures would be something like `\setmainfont{NewComputerModern}[Ligatures=NoCommon]`. See the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: @Diaa However, in this case `\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}` just means to load the Regular weight instead of the Book weight of New Computer Modern.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: you have to declare the bold font.

In the code I choose the font by file name as I'm not going to add SBL Greek to my system fonts.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\bgkfamily{SBL_grk}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bgreek}{\bgkfamily\upshape}

\begin{document}

Here is a sentence. This is \bgreek{και \textbf{και} και}

\end{document}
```

If you have the font installed among the system fonts, you can use

```
\newfontfamily\bgkfamily{SBL Greek}[
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]
```

I used 4 to make the boldfacing more evident.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ModernMTStd-Extended.otf}[
FakeBold=2,
Ligatures=TeX,
]

\setsansfont[%
FakeBold=2,
ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf}

\setmonofont[%
FakeBold=2,
ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}

\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}[FakeBold=2]
\let\mathbb\mathbbalt

\begin{document}
    This is how you fakebold \texttt{custom} \textsf{fonts}. You need to have the fonts specified in the \texttt{setmainfont} arguments installed on your machine or in the directory you are working on.
     \begin{align*}
         v\in\mathbb{V}\\
         f\in\mathbb{F}
     \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]